# CREATE TABLE a third table from two tables JOIN statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables and want to create a third one when ta asin_id and tb asin have the same value,

with the

```
SELECT * FROM ta JOIN tb ON ta.asin_id = tb.asin;
```

i can have the view from the third table but i cant create it.

i already tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE tc AS SELECT * FROM ta JOIN tb ON ta.asin_id = tb.asin;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "tc"
LINE 1: CREATE tc AS SELECT * FROM items JOIN bs_audiotv ON items.as...
```

i attached a pic from the shell here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/LLjHi2wn9WQhxXkR8

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 - you could easily copy and paste the text from the console. But the statement in that picture is different to the one in your question here. `create t as select  ...` in your picture, `create TABLE t as select ...` in this question - and that would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE T` is not a right syntax. You have to use `CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME AS`

When you are using CTAS you should specify which columns you need one by one. If same column name exists in your tables then you will receive an error again.

[CTAS](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-table-as/)

Here is you script.

```
CREATE TABLE TC
AS
   SELECT ITEMS.ASIN_ID,
          ITEMS.TITLE,
          ITEMS.BRAND,
          ITEMS.DESCRIPTION,
          ITEMS.CATEGORIES,
          ITEMS.SPECIFICATIONS,
          ITEMS.IMAGES,
          BS_AUDIOTV.ASIN,
          BS_AUDIOTV.LINK,
          BS_AUDIOTV.PRICE_L,
          BS_AUDIOTV.PRICE_U,
          BS_AUDIOTV.PRICE 
     FROM ITEMS JOIN BS_AUDIOTV ON ITEMS.ASIN_ID = BS_AUDIOTV.ASIN;
```

Comment: Sorry, i cchange # CREATE TABLE tc AS SELECT * FROM items JOIN bs_audiotv ON items.asin_id = bs_audiotv.asin;
ERROR:  column "id" specified more than once

Comment: In your select you should not use *. Because it could have more than one column with same name. You should specify columns one by one.

Comment: Thanks  @ismetguzelgun , i could create  without put *. i SELECT all the colums but didnt JOIN the second table,    # CREATE TABLE tc AS SELECT  asin_id,title,brand,description,categories,specifications,images FROM items JOIN bs_audiotv on items.asin_id = bs_audiotv.asin;

Comment: Could you share your intended table script in your question. Which columns you need and which column will be coming from which table ?

Comment: I dont have a script, im working directly with the shell, from TABLE items i need the asin_id, title, brand, description, categories, specifications, images and from TABLE  bs_audiotv need to be asin, link, price_l, price_u, price theres no repeating colums names,

Comment: Edited my answer. Pls check it.